# loading gridview with hyperlink column

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview and added a column "Hyperlink" to all records by enabling autogeneratefields.
When this gridview is loaded and when I click the hyperlink across any record I want to redirect to some other page with entire record passed as query string to that page?
can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

These links should clarify how to do it:

[How to pass variables thru a DataGrid hyperlink column](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4372)

[How To: Use a HyperLink control inside a GridView](http://www.keithrull.com/2006/09/11/HowToUseAHyperLinkControlInsideAGridView.aspx)

Sample code (Look at the NavigateUrl property of HyperLink):

```
<asp:GridView ID="urlGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>

   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"
                  runat="server"
                  NavigateUrl='<%# "RedirectPage.aspx?xxxx=" &
                  DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.xxxx") &
                 "&yyyy=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.yyyy")%>'
                  Text="Go!">
   </asp:HyperLink>

     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteName" HeaderText="Site Name" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Am not passing any variables to hyperlink column.The thing is that when I click the link across any record i have to be redirected to some other page with the record as querysting.

supposing you have a gridview of the following format,

  Name Address 
  xxxx yyyyy   BID
  aaaa bbbbb   BID

when I click the BID link at the first record,it should be directed to next page with  xxxx,yyyy as querystring.

thanks

Comment: The pages I linked above show you how to do just that... You can choose which row fields you want to be passed in the query string.