# Gridview ItemTemplate OnClientClick javascript function with DataItem value as parameter

Tags: asp.net, gridview, onclientclick

I have a button inside my `<ItemTemplate>` in GridView and I want to call a javascript function on the `OnClientClick` of that button passing the DataItem value as a parameter of the javascript function

```
<ItemTemplate>
    // Labels and Html styles
    ....
    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClientClick='javascript:CreateEditAddress(<%#Bind("Id") %>);' />
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

If I will not put a parameter in `CreateEditAddess()` this works well but I need the parameter.

I know I can put the OnClientClick event value in OnRowDataBound event of the gridview but I don't want to put it in CodeBehind.  It seems like the server tag is not parsed correctly.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

[loading gridview with hyperlink column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315991/loading-gridview-with-hyperlink-column/3316023#3316023)

I think you should use `DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.YourProperty")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link"> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HLink" 
          Text='<%# Eval("FirstName").ToString() + " " + Eval("LastName").ToString()%>' 
          NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:OpenPopup(" + "&#39;" + Eval("EmpId") + "&#39;);"   %> ' />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This will help you when there is need to pass one or more variables to javascript function.