# sending gridview column name value from one page to another page

Tags: gridview

I have grid view with column names categoryid  and category name.

I want to send the category id value to another page.

I have bit confused for sending this information. I know using "Request.querystring" we can get the

information from any page.

i dont know whether it is applicable to grid view cloumns or not.

would any one pls suggest any idea about this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the CategoryID column as a TemplateField with a Hyperlink.  See this question for sample code:

[loading gridview with hyperlink column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315991/loading-gridview-with-hyperlink-column)

You can then reference CategoryID from the next page using Request.Querystring, just like you would with any other Querystring variable.